# Does shutter speed in av mode is abstract?

Tags: canon, shutter-speed

I have a question if I shoot at around 8 a.m in the morning (usually bright outside) and I want to use aperture priority ( I know I can change the shutter speed) but does it gives a good speed if its bright and with iso of 100 or 200? or it's going to be a bad shutter speed given by the camera in that moment?

Thanks!

Comment: What is a good speed?

Comment: i mean shutter speed sorry

Comment: Are you shooting statues or passing race-cars?

Comment: ? The idea is that if you pay attention, you can then SEE what the shutter speed is, and if not satisfactory, you can adjust for a different plan.

Comment: @Jorgeluis: please edit your question so that it is more intelligible.

Comment: Look up [sunny 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunny_16_rule).

Comment: Im shooting turtles, i think im gonna go for av mode since its going to be bright enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hum. I gess light at 8am depends if you do not live in the Arctic Circle in winter.

Normally I would answer... find out. We are on the digital era where you can experiment and see the results in the moment. But the basic answer is yes... whatever a "good speed" is.

AV calculates the speed acording to the aperture. As you have plenty of speeds to choose from it is a good option.

Using Shutter priority on the contrary is more limited, because you do not have that much apertures to choose from.

---

Edited. Ok it is shutter speed. Yes that will change acordingly.

If you have the case that playing with the aperture wide open, you still find your photo moved, for example with a racing car, you aditionally need to move your ISO settings to, let us say 400-800.

Take some moments to read about: https://photo.stackexchange.com/search?q=exposure+triangle

Comment: I do not live near the Artic Circle, soo i would be okay if its really sunny and just use av mode? and keep with 100 iso?

Answer (score 3):

First off you've got to define a "good" and "bad" shutter speed.

The camera does not know good or bad. It knows light; it measures the amount of light that hits the metering sensor and sets exposure accordingly (taking into account the metering mode). It may take into account the lens' focal length if you're using Auto ISO (some cameras do), but that's about it.

The metering sensor (or any sensor for that matter), however, has a certain range in which it gives an accurate reading (consult your camera's specifications for that) - if it's too dark for example, the camera may tell you that the light is insufficient.

Comment: Drop the 'r' please :D